# How can I allow anyone with an AWS IAM key read-only access to a bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to make a few sample datasets available to anyone with an AWS IAM key so that they can learn how to use data files stored in S3 with a database. I thought that there was a choice to allow any authenticated user, but I cannot find a way to do this (it has been a couple years since I did this in the past).

I tried using the docs and sample configs provided by AWS, but I don't see what I want and since this is a security related matter I am looking for expert advice.

This is what I thought would be appropriate until I dug deeper in the docs, and now I think that this makes the object public:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1691165563530",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Allow any AWS authenticated user to get this single file",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit:

I think that a condition on top of `*` as the Principal limits read access to only authenticated users. Is this correct?

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": "*",
  "Action": "s3:GetObject",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/*",
  "Condition": {
    "StringLike": {
      "aws:userId": "AWS:authuser"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Believe that `*` and `AWS:*` are effectively the same for S3. See [Grant anonymous permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html#s3-anonymous-permissions) where it says "For anonymous users, these two methods are equivalent." To be honest, the docs are a bit misleading here.

Comment: I think you are correct @jarmod

Comment: When testing this you can use the awscli (`aws s3 cp ...`). To test unauthenticated/anonymous users, supply the `--no-sign-request` option on the awscli command line.

Comment: Your first example should work fine. However, please note that they will not be able to _List_ the contents of the bucket. They must know the Key (filename) of the object exactly to be able to access it.